# Why windowsphone.stackexchange.com is still beta?

Tags: discussion

I am just curious why the windowsphone.stackexchange.com still running as beta version. When it will be a release candidate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When, if ever, a Stack Exchange site graduates from beta is a more complex issue than the [Area 51 dashboard](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) might imply. Simply getting an "Okay" or better in the five categories listed there is no guarantee of graduating.

Stack Exchange sites graduate when they've reached a certain level of maturity, including a self-sustaining community with enough high-rep users to moderate the site, and a healthy amount of incoming traffic (ideally mostly from search engines). A graduation-ready site is also expected to show maintained growth in user and post count with no sign of stopping.

For more information, see [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate)

If you want to help contribute to this site, the easiest way to do that is by [voting](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: I was going to write a stand alone answer on behalf of the SE team, but @Indrek pretty much said it.

Answer (score 1):

The site gets a good number of visitors, but it doesn't get very many questions asked per day.
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

I think the site would move out of beta if that metric was to improve.

Comment: Nothing else? :|